# Cannot evaluate surface integral over ParametricRegion with Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to compute surface integral $\iint x\ dS$. The surface is given parametrically: $x=3t+1, y=a^3 \sin t, z=a^3 \cos t, a \in [\frac12, 1], t \in [\frac\pi6,\frac\pi4]$.

My code is:

```
R = ParametricRegion[{3*t + 1, a^3 * Sin[t], 
    a^3*Cos[t]}, {{a, 1/2, 1}, {t, Pi/6, Pi/4}}];
Integrate[x, {x, y, z} \[Element] R ]
```

However it does not compute the integral.
Please tell me what is wrong.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Strange because NIntegrate does compute the answer.

Comment: In version 11.0.1, even `NIntegrate` doesn't work for me...

Comment: I see this question more as a "why isn't the functionality working the way it should".  Either there is something off about the input, or something off about the program. The integral is doable as Henrik has shown. I don't see anything obvious wrong with the input.  Playing around with some test functions makes me believe it has something to do with the inclusion of trig functions. - Possible bug?

Comment: I think you should report this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We learnt how to do that by hand in the old days, you know:

```
Block[{t, a},
 F = {t, a} \[Function] {3*t + 1, a^3*Sin[t], a^3*Cos[t]};
 DF = {t, a} \[Function] Evaluate[D[F[t, a], {{t, a}, 1}]];
 jacobidet = {t, a} \[Function]  Evaluate[Simplify[
   Sqrt[Det[Transpose[DF[t, a]].DF[t, a]]]
 ]];
];
Integrate[F[t, a][[1]] jacobidet[t, a], {a, 1/2, 1}, {t, Pi/6, Pi/4}]
```

> ```
> (π (8 + 5 π) (64 Sqrt[10] - Sqrt[577] + 576 ArcCsch[3] - 576 ArcCsch[24]))/12288
> ```

**Edit**

Added also some bullet proofing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does not what I need, however you should add (3*t+1) factor to jacobidet

Comment: @Hedgehog I have checked this code and it does not work.

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas What's the issue?

Comment: @José, if you want to help people debug their code, you could write something more elaborate than "it does not work".

Comment: Ah, I see now. @Henrik, it should be `F[t, a]`, not `F[a, t]` in your integral. In the meantime, let me also present this alternate formula: `Integrate[(Function[{x, y, z}, x] @@ F[t, a]) Norm[Cross @@ Transpose[DF[t, a]]], {a, 1/2, 1}, {t, π/6, π/4}]`

Comment: @J.M. Oh my. Thank you for the _constructive_ remark! I hope it's better now...

Comment: @J.M. I apologize. My kernel was not clear :((  Anyway the error I obtain was too complex to be included in a comment

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas Ha, that's precisely what I thought. Well, it made us looking at it again and to correct another error, so it's okay.

Comment: @José, as a tip for next time: usually people don't really need the message text; it suffices to just get the message name, which you can get in current versions by clicking the "..." icon to the left of an error message, and then clicking on "Copy Message Name" in the resulting popup menu. In older versions, it's the part with `::` before the actual error message (e.g. `Power::infy` when you try evaluating `1/0`).

Comment: @J.M. got it ! Thx

Answer (score 2):

At least since *v13.3*, `Integrate` handles the problem without difficulty:

[image]

Comment: That works in 13.2.1.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Feel free to edit, it's a community wiki :) .